# Undoing SVN load on Repository or Clean Restart

Tags: svn

Is there a simple way to restart your repo to revision 0? For instance, I loading in a dump file which introduced a series of revisions. Now, I want to revert my repository back to revision 0.

My attempt:

```
svnadmin create loader
svnadmin load loader < some_dump.dump
svnadmin dump -r 0 > rev0.dump
svnadmin load loader < rev0.dump
```

However, nothing happens when I do the steps above. Why is this? Is it because loading a dump doesn't overwrite a previously loaded dump when the revision numbers overlap?

Comment: Just delete the repository and recreate it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I have been doing that but I was wondering if there was a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).  Try `svn merge --change -revision_number`, where `-revision_number` is the number of the revision you want to go back to, which in your case looks like it will be `-0`.